# setup.py/setup.cfg install all extras

Tags: installation, setuptools, setup.py

I search for a possibility to 'inherit' other extras in the setup.cfg like so:

```
[options.extras_require]
all =
    <doc>
    <dev>
    <test>
doc =
    sphinx
dev =
    dvc
    twine  # for publishing
    <test>
test =
    flake8
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    coverage
    pytest-shutil
    pytest-virtualenv
    pytest-fixture-config
    pytest-xdist
```

I wish to install all extras by running

```
pip install PACKAGE[all]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe *setuptools* uses [`configparser`'s `BasicInterpolation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.BasicInterpolation) when parsing the `setup.cfg` files. So you could use that to your advantage to do something like the following:

```
[options.extras_require]
all =
    %(doc)s
    %(dev)s
    %(test)s
doc =
    sphinx
dev =
    dvc
    twine  # for publishing
    %(test)s
test =
    flake8
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    coverage
    pytest-shutil
    pytest-virtualenv
    pytest-fixture-config
    pytest-xdist
```

Build the `sdist` then look at the `*.egg-info/requires.txt` file for your project for the result. Since `test` is included in `all` twice, once directly and once indirectly via `dev`, there will be some repetitions in `all`, but most likely it shouldn't be much of an issue.

---

Another solution, that theoretically should work with all build back-ends and front-ends is to "self-depend":

```
[options.extras_require]
all =
    PROJECT[doc]
    PROJECT[dev]
    PROJECT[test]
doc =
    sphinx
dev =
    dvc
    twine  # for publishing
    PROJECT[test]
test =
    flake8
    pytest
    pytest-cov
    coverage
    pytest-shutil
    pytest-virtualenv
    pytest-fixture-config
    pytest-xdist
```

***References***:

- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/10393
- https://discuss.python.org/t/pyproject-toml-optional-dependencies-redundancy-aka-dry-extras/8428